# Changing Datatype in table without losing existing column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column of varch(2) and it needs to be changed to Varchar(3) or 4.  Do I need to create a new column and copy the data from the old to the new?  New incoming data needs the bigger colunm.  It is going from OH and EI and needs to accommodate TBO  and IEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
   ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN YourCol VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
```

This is a metadata only change and not a size of data change.

Change `NOT NULL` to `NULL` if appropriate.

Comment: see the heap re: Xmas drinkies @Martin Smith

Answer (score 1):

No, you should be able to change the width of the existing varchar(2) column by using:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_column VARCHAR(4) [NOT] NULL 
-- new type at the end, NULL or NOT NULL as needed.
```

The other way around would not work though as the server would disallow narrowing that could lead to truncation.

The change is not allowed if the column is used in a PRIMARY KEY or [FOREIGN KEY] REFERENCES constraint though.

Comment: It is allowed in a column participating in a PK. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11122831/73226) Though your exact syntax wouldn't be. As if you don't specify `not null` allowing `null` is the result. And *that* isn't allowed in a PK.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, the last part came straight from the books online for [alter table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), I assumed it was correct.

Comment: @jpw it's correct about the foreign key. It also can't be altered if it's the target of an FK reference.

Comment: I was told they'd fixed it. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/768134/documentation-for-alter-table-alter-column-restrictions-needs-reviewing. Clearly not!