# Error altering a table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I have a SQL database and a table in that. I also have a Visual studio Windows Forms Project. I have added this database as a datasource to my project.

I have code in which I access and update this table. Now I want to change the datatype of a column. But when I alter the table I get a message as follows:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The object 'PK__Doctors__DD69A72236C6DD45' is dependent on column 'MedAssistID'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 2
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN MedAssistID failed because one or more objects access this column.
>   Table Structure:

```
ID(primary)  Name  Age  Password
  1              Sam    12    sam2003
  5             Dan     69   dsheen01
  12            louis    100   haml999
  3             Pat      23   pat2005
```

How can I change the datatype of ID?

Comment: Show us the table structure, and which column are you trying to change to what??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alter Column datatype with primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118568/alter-column-datatype-with-primary-key)

Comment: Drop the primary key, alter the column then add the key again.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thankyou for the help.I would be pleased if you could explain the logic behind your answer.

Comment: Well, what is the *current* datatype, and what do you want to change it to??

Comment: @Arvinder first, changing an int to varchar is a *very* strange decision that smells of a bad design - trying to store business data in the key. If you want a larger key, just use a bigint. Second, there's no logic to explain - if you want to modify a column that's used in constraints or indexes, materialized views etc, first you have to drop the other objects, make the change then rebuild them. Or use the table designer in SSMS - it will do the same if possible

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Firstly i was storing int type values in ID but now i  want to store letters also in it.I have changed the code in my project for this

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop all the relationships to this column
2. Edit the data type for this column (PK)
3. Edit the data type for relationship columns (FKs)
4. Recreate the relationships